# Delphi 7 delete some character from memo lines

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have the lines in memo like:

```
111111.kll
222222.kll
```

I need to remove last 4 char from each line to obtain result like:

```
111111
222222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to GolezTrol's solution, you can manipulate the Memo content directly, instead of making a copy of it in memory first:

```
var
  i, LineStart, LineLen: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LineStart := Memo1.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, i, 0);
      LineLen := Memo1.Perform(EM_LINELENGTH, LineStart, 0);
      Memo1.Perform(EM_SETSEL, LineStart + LineLen - 4, LineStart + LineLen);
      Memo1.SelText := '';
    end;
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Adding BeginUpdate will sure make it faster (faster than just changing the lines directly, I mean). In speed it will probably not beat the stringlist, but this version is probably more memory-efficient (that is, unless the internals of the memo control in Windows also make full copies on write). Still, though interesting, I think it is a bit awkward to mix the standard methods of TMemo with some of the messages it uses internally.

Answer (score 2):

With a [`for` loop](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=For), you can iterate over the lines. Using [`copy`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Copy), you can get a part of a line and assign it back to the line:

```
for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  Memo1.Lines[i] := Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 1, Length(Memo1.Lines[i]) - 4);
```

Now, changing the lines of a memo isn't very fast, so if you have many lines, you may want to use a stringlist instead. You can process all the lines in the stringlist, and only put them back in the memo after you're done. That way, the contents of the memo change only one time:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Text := Memo1.Text;
    for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      sl[i] := Copy(sl[i], 1, Length(sl[i]) - 4);
    Memo1.Text := sl.Text;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is faster and more memory-efficient to use the `TStrings.Assign()` method instead of the `TStrings.Text` property, eg: `sl.Assign(Memo1.Lines); ... Memo1.Lines.Assign(sl);`

Comment: More memoery-efficient? Yes, `.Text` will get a string that contains a copy of everything in the stringlist. Faster? In general that is true, but I'm not so sure for TMemoStrings, since it probably calls `.Put` and therefore a series of messages for each line. By setting the Text of the memo directly (not of its lines), you bypass that. I'd have to test to make sure.

Comment: Yes, using `Assign()` would call `TMemoStrings.Insert()` (not `Put()`) for each line, which would use a series of `EM_LINEINDEX`/`EM_LINELENGTH`/`EM_SETSEL`/`EM_REPLACESEL` messages. On the other hand, setting the `Text` property does use a single `WM_SETTEXT` message, but it also has other overhead, as `TMemoStrings` normalizes the line breaks of the new text using `AdjustLineBreaks()`, and then compares the resulting text to `WM_GETTEXTLEN` and `WM_GETTEXT` before issuing `WM_SETTEXT` if there is a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a specif function to replace characters. If you want to remove ".kll" for example there is no need to use a Loop.

```
  Memo1.Lines.Text := StringReplace(Memo1.Lines.Text,'.kll','',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Hope it helps!